# Infopath is publishing the form with old name

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, form

I have renamed the infopath task form in sharepoint designer.

For Example:

- Old Name is: `task_034_028_.xsn`
- Renamed to : `Task1.xsn`

After editing the form in infopath i am going to publish it but it publishing the form with old name on same location.

I tried clearing cache of infopath, SPD but no luck. What should i do? Please help.